# Changing return key into tab function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a client who wants the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key to perform the same function as the <kbd>tab</kbd> key on form fields.

Here's my code so far. It won't work. Anyone know why?

```
<script>
$('input, select').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            var focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
            focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)-1).focus(); 
        }
        else {
            var focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
            focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1).focus();
            return true;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll want to prevent the default behavior of the enter key with `preventDefault();`
2. You put `form.find` in there, but I don't see `form` set anywhere. Maybe try `$('form')`?

I've set up a basic [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svpmz08s/) for you to check out. Is this the functionality you were going for?

```
$('input, select').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            var focusable = $('form').find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
            focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) - 1).focus();
        } else {
            var focusable = $('form').find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
            focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) + 1).focus();
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that `.live()` is deprecated and you could just use `.on()`

Comment: You're right about the form.find. That was my problem. It should've just been 
    $('input ....